# SharePoint 2010 Navigation error: An unexpected error occured while manipulating the navigational structure of this Web, August 2012 CU

Tags: 2010, error, navigation, quick-launch, cumulative-update

has anyone experienced/fixed this problem in their environment?

Our publishing site has the August 2012 Cumulative Update installed and has been running fine for over a month. Now, since the site has been made available to a wider audience, the navigation is causing errors.

On further investigation, there are huge numbers of duplicates for manually created links in the Quick Launch Navigation.

Apparently this can sometimes be fixed by "tidying up" the NavNodes table in the database using PowerShell commands. Does anyone know of any reliable way to solve this and also how to prevent it in future?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue, Microsoft Engineer called me back to confirm this is a known bug with the August 2012 Cumulative Update and we are best to roll it back to July.  Regrettably this involves pretty much building another farm from scratch as we started building our site on August CU.

Answer (score 0):

We were plagued with this problem; installing the April 2013 Cumulative Update fixed it.  However, the April 2013 CU introduces a new problem with taxonomies - you get an error message when you check out a page with taxonomy fields.